# Is there any advanced clipboard managers (Clipx in Windows) for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: clipboard, ubuntu-16.04

Is there any advanced clipboard managers for Ubuntu 16.04 that can easily store copied items? (Like ClipX in Windows)

For example I might want to copy several items in the clipboard:

1. copy_text
2. other_text
3. another_text
4. .jpg image file
5. etc.

Then when I press Ctrl+ALT+V it'll show a list of copied items from clipboard history after it, I choose my desired text from that list it'll be pasted.

Are there any clipboard manager that very handy and support many features for ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/584296/281086). Moreover, Diodon and Klipper are best.

Answer (score 0):

These resources might get you started:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/584034/ubuntu-14-04-clipboard-manager
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-tools-manage-linux-clipboard/
- http://www.tecmint.com/best-clipboard-managers-for-linux/

Comment: Thanks . but which one is best u suggest?

Comment: That depends on your Desktop Environment and personal preference, I suggest you try them out and pick the one you like most.